# Javascript Hide/Show Classes Issue

Tags: javascript, class

I have the following function that is supposed to get all elements in a document with the given class:

```
function getElementByClass(objClass)
{
//  This function is similar to 'getElementByID' since there is no inherent function to     get an element by it's class
    var elements = (ie) ? document.all : document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
{
    alert(elements[i].className);
    alert(objClass);
    if (elements[i].className==objClass)
    {
        return elements[i]
    }
}
}
```

When I call this function with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(getElementByClass('done'));</script>
```

Nothing happens. Is there something wrong with the function?

Comment: Why not just use a library like jQuery? That way you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I hate to be this person but, why not use jQuery, thenn all you have to do is `$(".class_name")` and you have them all.

Comment: Fairly new to javascript, haven't gone as far as jQuery yet. Do I have to install anything to get jQuery working?
EDIT: I've thrown the jQuery source on my website now, I wasn't aware it worked just like a simple .js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function does not get **all** elements with that class name, it gets one.  And what is your intent with the way you are calling it?  `document.write` seems like a funny thing to do with a DOM element already on your page.

I hate to just say "use jquery"... but you probably should.

Aside from the missing declaration of `ie`, this function does work.  One problem you will have with it is if you have multiple classes on an element, this function won't work.

Comment: I believe I will be using jQuery to do this now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('done');
```

EDIT:

src: http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/

```
/*
    Developed by Robert Nyman, http://www.robertnyman.com
    Code/licensing: http://code.google.com/p/getelementsbyclassname/
*/
var getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm){
    if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
        getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm) {
            elm = elm || document;
            var elements = elm.getElementsByClassName(className),
                nodeName = (tag)? new RegExp("\\b" + tag + "\\b", "i") : null,
                returnElements = [],
                current;
            for(var i=0, il=elements.length; i<il; i+=1){
                current = elements[i];
                if(!nodeName || nodeName.test(current.nodeName)) {
                    returnElements.push(current);
                }
            }
            return returnElements;
        };
    }
    else if (document.evaluate) {
        getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm) {
            tag = tag || "*";
            elm = elm || document;
            var classes = className.split(" "),
                classesToCheck = "",
                xhtmlNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
                namespaceResolver = (document.documentElement.namespaceURI === xhtmlNamespace)? xhtmlNamespace : null,
                returnElements = [],
                elements,
                node;
            for(var j=0, jl=classes.length; j<jl; j+=1){
                classesToCheck += "[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + classes[j] + " ')]";
            }
            try {
                elements = document.evaluate(".//" + tag + classesToCheck, elm, namespaceResolver, 0, null);
            }
            catch (e) {
                elements = document.evaluate(".//" + tag + classesToCheck, elm, null, 0, null);
            }
            while ((node = elements.iterateNext())) {
                returnElements.push(node);
            }
            return returnElements;
        };
    }
    else {
        getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm) {
            tag = tag || "*";
            elm = elm || document;
            var classes = className.split(" "),
                classesToCheck = [],
                elements = (tag === "*" && elm.all)? elm.all : elm.getElementsByTagName(tag),
                current,
                returnElements = [],
                match;
            for(var k=0, kl=classes.length; k<kl; k+=1){
                classesToCheck.push(new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + classes[k] + "(\\s|$)"));
            }
            for(var l=0, ll=elements.length; l<ll; l+=1){
                current = elements[l];
                match = false;
                for(var m=0, ml=classesToCheck.length; m<ml; m+=1){
                    match = classesToCheck[m].test(current.className);
                    if (!match) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (match) {
                    returnElements.push(current);
                }
            }
            return returnElements;
        };
    }
    return getElementsByClassName(className, tag, elm);
};
```

Comment: Not available in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

if you have posted full source then what is ie in 
       var elements = (ie) ? document.all : document.getElementsByTagName('*');
try to track error via firebug.

Answer (score 1):

`var elements = (ie)` is referencing an undefined variable `ie`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a JavaScript library?  Functions like this have been written many [times before](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/dom/), painful to waste time on these kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use getElementsByClassName when available.